# Values are retrieved as null even if the JSON files have values to keys

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON file which looks like:

```json
{
  "caseNumber": "kblndw896",
  "features": [
    {
         "id1": "wad12jkb",
         "id2": "jBgioj",
         "id3": "jabd8&",
         "limit": "500000",
         "M1": "333487.2",
         "M2": "339259.88",
         "M3": "316003.84",
         "M4": "219097.12",
         "M5": "393842.98",
         "M6": "498684.1",
         "M7": "1074002.44",
         "M8": "437211.19",
         "M9": "444842.35",
         "M10": "657756.22",
         "M11": "571928.78",
         "M12": "230378.06"
      }
  ]
}
```

Now I'm trying to import this file and put in the POJO class called Payload, which has features POJO class as child. Now when I import using `ObjectMapper`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
Payload payload= mapper.readValue(new File("filepath\\file.json"),
                Payload.class);
```

then I'm getting this imported in the payload POJO class, but the values for keys in features array has null value for all the keys.

Example, the imported data is:

```json
{
  "caseNumber": "kblndw896",
  "features": [
    {
      "id1": null,
      "id2": "null",
      "id3": "null",
      "limit": null,
      "m7": null,
      "m6": null,
      "m9": null,
      "m4": null,
      "m11": null,
      "m8": null,
      "m2": null,
      "m12": null,
      "m1": null,
      "m3": null,
      "m5": null,
      "m10": null
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I get values from file?

Tried:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
Payload payload= mapper.readValue(new File("filepath\\file.json"),
                Payload.class);
```

Expected:

```json
{
  "caseNumber": "kblndw896",
  "features": [
    {
         "id1": "wad12jkb",
         "id2": "jBgioj",
         "id3": "jabd8&",
         "limit": "500000",
         "M1": "333487.2",
         "M2": "339259.88",
         "M3": "316003.84",
         "M4": "219097.12",
         "M5": "393842.98",
         "M6": "498684.1",
         "M7": "1074002.44",
         "M8": "437211.19",
         "M9": "444842.35",
         "M10": "657756.22",
         "M11": "571928.78",
         "M12": "230378.06"
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: [tag:objectmapper] is a _Swift_ library, are you using [tag:jackson]?

Comment: What does the Payload class look like? I see you're trying to ignore case, but you're not configuring the mapper, you're configuring a different builder you're not actually using. Perhaps the mismatch is the issue?

Comment: @ZufarSunagatov i tried out your approach which is very similar to what i did earlier , its not working for me , i get null in the values of keys in features array json

Comment: @jonrsharpe nope it is jackson databind library

Comment: @Kraylog sorry , that was done mistakenly , i have edited it in question

Comment: Please post the code for `Features` class, specially, what is the getter/setter, because `m7` for example would have `getM7()`, which works. I think having `getm7()` isn't a valid getter.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

This is `class Features`

```
public class Features {
    private String id1;
    private String id2;
    private String id3;
    private String limit;
    private String m1;
    private String m2;
    private String m3;
    private String m4;
    private String m5;
    private String m6;
    private String m7;
    private String m8;
    private String m9;
    private String m10;
    private String m11;
    private String m12;

    // getters and setters below
}
```

This is `class Payload`

```
public class Payload {
    private String caseNumber;
    private List<Features> features;

    // getters and setters below
}
```

And finally:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
Payload payload = objectMapper.readValue(new File("filepath\\file.json"), Payload.class);
System.out.println(payload);
```

Comment: This is not working for me, my previous approach was very similar and im still getting null in features array json. I have Payload pojo class and there is features pojo class which